# else if expected expression c++ / Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have seen this problem around the forum but I have not been able to fix this issue. After all "else if" Xcode can't compile, it tells me that it is a "parse issue" and that requieres an "expected expression".

I know that it is a beginner's question but I truly want to understand what is wrong with my code, why it keeps telling me expected expression after each esle if...

---

```
if (TypeStrat == 1)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSPrixPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSDeltaPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (2*BSVega(S,K,T,r,v))         << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSRhoPut(S,K,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0) + (BSThetaPut(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;

        else if (TypeStrat == 2)
        {
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
            cin >> K1;
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
            cin >> K2;

            cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
            cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
            cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) + (BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
            << "journalier" << endl;
        }

        else if (TypeStrat == 3)
        {
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
            cin >> K1;
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du short Call ?" << endl;
            cin >> K2;

            cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSPrixCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSDeltaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
            cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSRhoCall(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
            cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - (BSThetaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
            << "journalier" << endl;
        }

        else if (TypeStrat == 4)
        {
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
            cin >> K1;
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du short Put ?" << endl;
            cin >> K2;

            cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
            cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
            cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaPut(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - (BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
            << "journalier" << endl;
        }

        else if (TypeStrat == 5)
        {
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
            cin >> K1;
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice des deux short Call ?" << endl;
            cin >> K2;

            cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSPrixCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSDeltaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
            cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSRhoCall(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
            cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - 2*(BSThetaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
            << "journalier" << endl;
        }

        else if (TypeStrat == 6)
        {
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
            cin >> K1;
            cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice des deux short Put ?" << endl;
            cin >> K2;

            cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
            cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
            cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
            cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaPut(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - 2*(BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
            << "journalier" << endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did it occur to you that the formatting is strange? Did you think about why that might be the case?

Answer (score 2):

An `else if` requires a preceding `if` statement. The block of `if` statement that precedes your first `else if` is not closed, i.e. an ending curly brace `}` is missing. Also, there is an extra `}` in the end.

Missing curly brace:

```
if (TypeStrat == 1)
{
    cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
    cin >> K1;
    cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
    cin >> K2;

    cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSPrixPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
    cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSDeltaPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
    cout << "Vega  " << (2*BSVega(S,K,T,r,v))         << endl;
    cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSRhoPut(S,K,T,r,v))   << endl;
    cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0) + (BSThetaPut(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0)
    << "journalier" << endl;

 //  }  <-- Insert ending curly brace here
    else if (TypeStrat == 2)
```

Extra curly brace:

```
else if (TypeStrat == 6)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice des deux short Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaPut(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - 2*(BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }

}     //   <-- Remove this extra curly brace
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like have a `}` in the wrong place. Is the following what you intended. Removed } from end and added before `else if (TypeStrat == 2)`

```
    if (TypeStrat == 1)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSPrixPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSDeltaPut(S,K,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (2*BSVega(S,K,T,r,v))         << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K,T,r,v) + BSRhoPut(S,K,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0) + (BSThetaPut(S,K,T,r,v)/365.0)
    << "journalier" << endl;
    }
    else if (TypeStrat == 2)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) + BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) + (BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }

    else if (TypeStrat == 3)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du short Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSPrixCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSDeltaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSRhoCall(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - (BSThetaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }

    else if (TypeStrat == 4)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du short Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaPut(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - (BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }

    else if (TypeStrat == 5)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice des deux short Call ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSPrixCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSDeltaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoCall(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSRhoCall(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaCall(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - 2*(BSThetaCall(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }

    else if (TypeStrat == 6)
    {
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice du long Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K1;
        cout << "Quel est le prix d'exercice des deux short Put ?" << endl;
        cin >> K2;

        cout << "Prix de la stratégie " << (BSPrixPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSPrixPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Delta " << (BSDeltaPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSDeltaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)) << endl;
        cout << "Vega  " << (BSVega(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSVega(S,K2,T,r,v))       << endl;
        cout << "Rho   " << (BSRhoPut(S,K1,T,r,v) - 2*BSRhoPut(S,K2,T,r,v))   << endl;
        cout << "Theta " << (BSThetaPut(S,K1,T,r,v)/365.0) - 2*(BSThetaPut(S,K2,T,r,v)/365.0)
        << "journalier" << endl;
    }
```